# Python : file transfer giving errors

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send a file from a server to client but get errors. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

This is my server code:

```
if msg in data.keys():
 print("Requested file exists", msg)
     f=open(msg,"rb")
     datam= f.read(1024)

     while (datam):

      if(s.send(datam)):

         print "sending data"

         datam = f.read(1024)



      s.close()

      f.close
else:
     print("File Not found",msg)
     print("File Not found",data.keys())
     c.close()                # Close the connection
```

where msg contains the path address where file exists
c=client socket   s=server socket
I want to read that file and send it to client but I get this error

```
Got connection from ('127.0.0.1', 42330)
('Requested file exists', '/home/beenish/Pictures/pew.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 41, in <module>
if(s.send(datam)):
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

On client side, I have written this code to recieve that file

```
s.listen(15)
f = open('\home\beenish\pictures\lol.txt', 'wb')
data = s.recv(1024)

while(data):


 f.write(data)

 data=s.recv(1024)

  f.close()
  s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

where s is the client socket

Here I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "client.py", line 26, in <module>
 s.listen(15)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
 return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
 socket.error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: It's good practice to put the send/reception into a try/catch/finally block : when the communication goes sour, you just close cleanly the socket and prevent your program from blowing up.

Answer (score 0):

On the client side you have an error on this line:

```
s.listen(15)
```

And the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) say that the argument has a system dependant maximum, usually 5. So try finding out the maximum for your system of just use a lower value and see what happen.

The server side error could be a side effect of the client side failure.

Answer (score 0):

That is the kind of error you get when you call [`socket.listen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.listen) before calling [`socket.bind`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind). Keep in mind that a server always has to follow the sequence `socket()`, `bind()`, `listen()` and `accept()` in that specific order.

Comment: On server side I am already following this same sequence. I think there is some problem with send method in while loop at server side but I am not sure...

Comment: @Zara I've checked it out again, and now I see something else: You are calling `bind` on the client, while you should only call to `socket()` and `connect()`.

Comment: Can you please elaborate... I don't get it

Comment: @Zara You only call `bind` on the code for the server, not the client. Check out [this example](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#example) to see the needed calls for a server and for a client.